# React-table not able to pass id in Link

Tags: react-table

I am not able to pass e.id or my product id at end of Link url. 
Can you please let me know what am i missing ?

Note: Proper Link is ready but not able to pass product id at end or url.

```
    const columns =[
    {
    Header: "Name",
    accessor: "name",
    filterable: true
    },
    {
    Header: "Action",
    Cell: e =><Link to={/admin/product/update/${e.id}}>
    Update </ span>
    </ Link>,
    filterable: false,
    sortable:false
    }
    ]

    <ReactTable
    columns={columns}
    data = {products}
    filterable
    sortable
    defaultPageSize={5}
    noDataText={"Please wait ...loading"}
    >
```

Answer (score 0):

You forget the **`**

```
<Link to={`/admin/product/update/${e.id}`}>
```

Answer (score 0):

After spending half hours i got the solution

{ 
        Header: "Edit",
        Cell: e =>< Link to={`/admin/product/update/${e.original._id}`}>
                    < span className="badge badge-warning badge-pill">
                        Update
                    
                ,
        filterable: false,
        sortable:false
    }